# Doing analytics on our managed package users

Tags: managed-package, analytics

My company is working on a free managed package which is supposed to be put on App Exchange (but not yet). I am just wondering is there a way/tool to help check out the analytics of the downloading? Something which works a bit like Google analytics, which shows how many people has downloaded the app; where are they from; are they using Salesforce classic or lightning. Is there an approach for us to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request the ISV usage metrics feature be enabled for your app: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/usage_metrics_intro.htm.

You will need to open a case and may need to get your Tech Evangelist involved but this will give you all that info plus more.